# Bigquery slot time consumed 4 days

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Firstly, I found my table size by running:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM `rayn-deen-app.analytics_317927526.events_*`
```

the answer was: 49487300

Now, I am running a query which is designed to get the latest Session Id and Session Number for users. I am following the tutorial: https://developers.google.com/analytics/bigquery/advanced-queries#user_pseudo_id

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION GetParamValue(params ANY TYPE, target_key STRING)
AS (
  (SELECT `value` FROM UNNEST(params) WHERE key = target_key LIMIT 1)
);

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION GetDateSuffix(date_shift INT64, timezone STRING)
AS (
  (SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(timezone), INTERVAL date_shift DAY)))
);

WITH removed AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT user_pseudo_id AS removed_users
  FROM `rayn-deen-app.analytics_317927526.events_*`
  WHERE event_name = "app_remove"
  AND DATE_TRUNC(EXTRACT(DATE from TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)), DAY) 
    BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
    AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
),
session_counts AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    user_pseudo_id,
    FIRST_VALUE(GetParamValue(event_params, 'ga_session_id').int_value)
      OVER (UserWindow) AS ga_session_id,
    FIRST_VALUE(GetParamValue(event_params, 'ga_session_number').int_value)
      OVER (UserWindow) AS ga_session_number
  FROM
    `rayn-deen-app.analytics_317927526.events_*`
    
  WHERE
    user_pseudo_id IN UNNEST((SELECT ARRAY_AGG(user_pseudo_id) FROM removed))
    AND RIGHT(_TABLE_SUFFIX, 8)
      BETWEEN GetDateSuffix(-30, 'Asia/Karachi')
      AND GetDateSuffix(0, 'Asia/Karachi')
  WINDOW UserWindow AS (PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id ORDER BY event_timestamp DESC)
)

SELECT *
FROM session_counts;
```

The problem is that the query has been running for several minutes, and the "Bigquery slot time consumed" that is being shown is upwards of 4 days! Any other queries I have run on this table have given results within one minute, is there anything I am doing that's incorrect? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be several reasons a where query execution might take more time.

Chances are that you might be hitting performance bug in BigQuery since your query is taking far too long before execution. Other reasons might include data volume, query complexity, insufficient resorce allocation (where you can try adjusting the query settings namely number of slots, memory allocation).

Since there can be multiple reasons, you can reach the Google Cloud Support team to have a look at the query to understand why it is running slow. You can create a support [ticket](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases), if you have a support package or create a thread on GCP [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list).